# Export csv to any other program user has on his system

Tags: php, csv

I want to export my db data to CSV or asking user "Open with his local supporting program".

Exporting to csv I could understand using this code:

```
<?php

header("Content-type: text/csv; charset=UTF-8");
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=Export.csv');
//connection
$con = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', '');
if(!$con){
    echo "Error connection";
}
//select db
$select_db = mysql_select_db('country', $con);
if(!$select_db){
    echo "Error to select database";
}
mysql_set_charset("utf8", $con);

//Mysql query to get records from datanbase
$user_query = mysql_query('SELECT * FROM countries');

//While loop to fetch the records
$contents = "ccode,country\n";
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($user_query))
{
    $contents.=$row['ccode'].",";
    $contents.=$row['country']."\n";
}

$contents_final = chr(255).chr(254).mb_convert_encoding($contents, "UTF-16LE","UTF-8");
print $contents_final;

?>
```

How 2nd part could be managed? Showing option to open with local installed program?
Above code is correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
header('Pragma: public');
header('Expires: 0');
header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
header('Cache-Control: private',false);
header('Content-Type: application/csv');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="your_file_name.csv"');
header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
```

This will cause the browser to display the dialog box to Save / Open the file.

You should also consider a) switching to mysqli_ or PDO and b) using PHP's built-in csv functions, e.g.

```
ob_start();
$f = fopen('php://output', 'w');
// $results comes from mysqli_ functions
foreach ( $results as $k => $v ) {
    fputcsv($f, $v);
}
$output = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();
echo $output;
```